# GoogleVR SDK and VLC library integrated via pod not working together in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, vlc, libvlc, google-vr-sdk

In my iOS application, I have to play 360 videos with ambisonic effect, so I have integrated the VLC library for these requirements. But later I have one more requirement support VR mode for playback, so I want to integrate GoogleVR SDK via pod. But after this integration, my application stops working with the following error

"[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:67] This program requires version 3.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 3.1.0.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "blaze-out/ios_x86_64-opt/genfiles/vr/courtside/proto/projection_proto.pb.cc".)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException"

If anyone knows the fix for this issue, please share that with me. If VLC can play VR Mode, then that would be fine.

Comment: check which version of protobuf both googleVR and VLC use and make them match

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
how can i check it,..? could you please get the steps here?

Comment: I dont know exactly. You should check the version of both googlevr and vlc, and go check their source code at that version. In there you will see the protobuf version used

Comment: can someone help on this?